# APNS settings in postman using certificate

Tags: ios, rest, apple-push-notifications, postman

I'm trying to create a request in Postman (prefer) to test the Push notification API out. My search mostly returned firebase or onesignal settings while I'm trying to send the request in raw directly to apple.

Can someone please help to setup and formulate a basic APNS request in postman?

I'm using this documentation [page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/) as a reference.

1. What I'm missing I think is where to specify the contents of the p12 file plus any other missing data.
2. I didn't get number 3 in the path variable.
   `:path =/3/device/00fc13adff785122b4ad28809a3420982341241421348097878e577c991de8f0`

---

```
Listing 2 A POST request relying on a certificate
HEADERS
  - END_STREAM
  + END_HEADERS
  :method = POST
  :scheme = https
  :path = /3/device/00fc13adff785122b4ad28809a3420982341241421348097878e577c991de8f0
  host = api.sandbox.push.apple.com
  apns-id = eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b
  apns-push-type = alert
  apns-expiration = 0
  apns-priority = 10
DATA
  + END_STREAM
  { "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
```

---

**Translated above into postman**

[image]

[image]

---

I've a curl command in case it helps (it's in http2 though). [Reference](https://gist.github.com/greencoder/16d1f8d7b0fed5b49cf64312ce2b72cc)

## Note: You MUST have curl 7.47+ with http/2 support compiled in

```
curl -v \
-d '{"aps":{"alert":"<message>","badge":42}}' \
-H "apns-topic: <bundle id>" \
-H "apns-priority: 10" \
--http2 \
--cert <certificate file> \
https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/<device token>
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution for this yet ? My question is : why you are not sending/referencing your .pem file ?

Comment: not yet, it's not clear that where do I put the contents of the pem file in the request.